# Generating a random sample of BigInt values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, floating-accuracy, bigint

For a game implemented in JavaScript, I need to produce a random list of `n` unique numbers in the range `[0, N)` where `N` may be greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. This poses three important challenges:

- Memory cost cannot be O(N), as we wouldn't have enough RAM. This means we cannot use a modified Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm to take `n` shuffled values from an array of `N` elements. (JS arrays are limited to 32-bit indexes, but we'd run out of RAM long before that.)
- Execution time should be as close as possible to O(n) and not O(N). I expect n to be relatively small (< 100).
- Most Math operations use double-precision floating point values and will not work with numbers this big.

I found a solution to the first two challenges in Kim-Hung Li's reservoir sampling algorithm L. To summarize, the idea behind this algorithm is that we shuffle the first `n` numbers to form an initial reservoir, then we progressively overwrite some of it with random numbers taken from the rest of the range. We use a geometric progression to determine how many numbers to skip on each iteration.

Assume that sampleSize is a number and populationSize is a BigInt in the following code:

```
// Creates an array initialized with [0n, 1n, ... BigInt(count-1)].
function bigRange (count) {
    const array = Array(count);
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
        array[i] = BigInt(i);
    }
    return array;
}

function bigSample (sampleSize, populationSize) {
    const reservoir = shuffle(bigRange(sampleSize));
    let record = BigInt(sampleSize);
    let weight = exp(log(random()) / sampleSize);

    while (true) {
        const skipCount = floor(log(random()) / log(1 - weight));
        record += BigInt(skipCount);

        if (record >= populationSize) {
            return reservoir;
        }

        reservoir[floor(random() * sampleSize)] = record;
        record += BigInt(1);
        weight *= exp(log(random()) / sampleSize);
    }
}
```

This code, however, will not work for arbitrarily large numbers as the precision of the floating point numbers is limited. As the populationSize grows, non-significant bits of the floating point numbers are eventually used and we no longer have uniform distribution, then we get into unsafe integer territory, and finally it's possible for `skipCount` to become `Infinity`. Knowing this, I'm left wondering...

- **At which point does this function become unreliable?**
- **Is there a way for me to improve this algorithm to compensate for JavaScript's limitations?**
- **Are there any better alternatives?**

Note that my knowledge of probability is limited, and I wrote this code after a week spent digging through scientific papers I barely understood. I do have an alternative approach, but it would be much less efficient and would require mixing random number generation with the puzzle generation logic.

Answer (score 2):

If `n` is relatively small, an alternative is to store numbers already generated in a JavaScript Map or ordinary JavaScript object, where the keys are the numbers (but note that both Maps and ordinary objects will convert those keys to strings, so that in that case, the key should be the same as the value).  If `n` is considerably less than `N` the time to store each new random number approaches constant time complexity, and the probability that all `n` out of `N` random numbers will be different on the first try approaches 1.

---

- I have written a section showing [various ways](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Sampling_Without_Replacement_Choosing_Several_Unique_Items) to sample `n` out of `N` items depending on how big `n` and `N` are.
- But if you're trying to generate `n` unique random numbers from a huge space of `N` possible values (e.g., 100-bit numbers), and those numbers are to identify something in some way, then there are several things to keep in mind, which I detail in "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)".

Comment: I just double-checked, Map and Set actually allows any value as a key, even BigInt, which I had forgotten because WeakMap only allows objects. I could call a pseudo-random BigInt generator n times and just retry whenever I generate a number I have already picked, that is indeed an option as long as `n/N` is small. I could verify this ratio and switch algorithm when viable. I'll look into it.

Comment: See the edit to my question, which discuss various ways to sample `n` out of `N` items depending on how big `n` and `N` are, and things to keep in mind with unique random numbers.

Comment: Wow, that's a very useful reference, thanks. I'll try implementing RNDINT using the Crypto API since `Math.random` is too loosely defined in the ECMAScript standard. I'll leave this question open in the meantime, but I'll likely end up marking this as the accepted solution and posting my final JS code in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your values bit by bit and add them to a trie. When you generate not the first number you can use the count of free space in the branches of your trie to identify probabilities to go into each branch. This will give unique numbers from uniform distribution if floating-point operations would have been perfect, but I guess these inconsistencies in probabilities at the high level in the trie won't make a significant difference (so, this needs further investigation). Note that if you generated a number, that is greater than N you just start generation process over. if you won't make unnecessary bits the probability of regeneration will be less than 50% and the expected value of the additional generations is one.

Comment: I did read about tries earlier this week, it was actually my original approach, but I couldn't find much information about them being used for random generation. If you have any reference I could consult I'm interested. I didn't mention this in the question because I'm also interested in a generic answer, but I actually know that `N=a**b` where `a` and `b` are small integers, meaning I could make a trie of depth `b` where nodes have exactly `a` children, avoiding the regeneration problem altogether.